# C# Re-use or re-create tasks?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I have a while loop in which I create and start tasks, as follows:

```
while (!stopped)
{
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        tasks.add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomething(i)));

    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}
```

Would I get better performance if the tasks are created once before the while loop, and restarted everytime (because the data being passed to the function never changes)?

Comment: You can't restart Task...

Comment: Task.factory is part of task parallel library, and already has optimizations built in- it won't start a new thread for every task you start. It would reuse a thread that it has in its 'pool'. What sort of work are u doing in each task?

Answer (score 0):

You can't restart task 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270682.aspx
By the way

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {....})
```

is fast than

```
Task task = new Task(() => {...});
task.Start();
```

because no locking on Start method.

In your case use async io to get performance boost.

Comment: I don't see any mention of IO in the question.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing fundamentally wrong with your code. This is a perfectly acceptable approach. You do not need to worry about the performance or expensive of creating tasks because the TPL was specifically designed to be used exactly like you have done.

However, there *is* one major problem with your code. You are [closing over the loop variable](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx). Remember, closures capture the *variable* and not the *value*. The way your code is written the `DoSomething` method will not be using the value of `i` that you think it should. Your code needs to be rewritten like this.

while (!stopped)
{
    List tasks = new List();

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    int capture = i;
    tasks.add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomething(capture)));
}

Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

}

As a side note you could use the `Parallel.For` method as an alternative. It is definitely a lot more compact of a solution if nothing else.

```
while (!stopped)
{
  Parallel.For(0, 10, i => DoSomething(i));
}
```